# Recource compilation failed

Tags: android-studio, gradle, compiler-errors

I faced with error today and I can't fix it. please help me it's drive me crazy.

```
     Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
      > A failure occurred while executing 
      com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable
        > Resource compilation failed. Check logs for details.
```

I've tried "clean code" and rebuild project and invalidate cache and restart. I also delete the idea.xml.but none of these didn't work

Comment: Scan through the xml files, must be an error in one or more.

Comment: when I update AGP and JRE its work but I don't know why?      thank you for answering  @JustInCoding

Comment: You can see the problem by scanning through the log generated as mentioned in `Resource compilation failed. Check logs for details.`

Comment: The output of log was really large and huge. So I terrified to take look at that.

Comment: Don't be terrified to read huge logs, 'cause you don't have to :). You just have to scan through the lines which indicate errors, and they usually start with `Caused by: java.xy.ZException`

Comment: Thanks you. That helps me a lot @justincoding

Comment: I also faced same problem. And I realized you don't need to go into logs because the error is also visible in the Build Output just that is a bit tricky to open. You just have to select on the first line of the Build Output and you will see details on the right window that opens with the full logs so that you can easily scroll to see exact errors.